# Sketchflow - grid datatemplate

Tags: grid, sketchflow

I am trying to do something very simple with Sketchflow. 
Create a grid with data. I tried using a listbox, created a datasource, bound the datasource to the listbox...everything works fine....but am stuck when it comes to trying to customize how the data is laid out....i.e., i want to create a data-template for the listbox, and then bind data to it.

any help on this would be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance,

Sashidhar Kokku

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do what you are suggesting, I suspect what you want to use is DataGrid.

For Silverlight you can find the DataGrid in the Silverlight Toolkit: http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight

For WPF you can find the DataGrid in the WPF Toolkit: http://www.codeplex.com/wpf